# Cannot open Realm using typescript 2.4.1 + react native 0.46.1 because Realm is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, realm

If I import realm using:

```
import {Realm} from "realm";
```

I cannot get Realm to open via:

```
const realm = new Realm({schema: [UserSchema]});
```

using typescript 2.4.1 and react native 0.46.1

Error I am receiving depending on how I import:

> TypeError: Realm is not a constructor

or

> Unhandled JS Exception: _realm.Realm is not a constructor

Opening async works fine :

```
Realm.open({schema: schema}).then((realm: Realm) => {
   //realm.write...then realm.create/delete/blah
})
```

Comment: Similar problems [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1226).
Use `import Realm from "realm"` execution fine, but show ts error `Module ''realm'' has no default export.`. But it's work.